# Why am I not able to get javac -version?

Tags: java, java-8, javac

i have  `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102 and C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
and C:\jdk1.8.0_121` and in command prompt , java -version giving java version 1.8.0_102 that is fine. but when I type `java`c -version , it giving `javac.exe` not compatible with your windows. But no problem in other systems with same jdk and windows. please do help

Comment: For windows 10 both are working

Comment: For windows 7 both are working.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I mix the comments

Comment: Something is wrong with your JDK installation.

Answer (score 2):

> javac.exe not compatible with your windows

Sounds like you've downloaded 64 bit JDK into C:\ but you're running 32bit Windows

The JRE does not contain javac, therefore the JDK is the problem

After you get a good version of Java, you'll need to fix your PATH variables

Answer (score 0):

32 bit Windows on which a 32 bit JRE was already installed. You now tried to install a 64 bit JDK on it as well, which doesn't work.

The 32 bit JRE is still there, and as some installers will put java.exe and some others in your Windows installation (windows/system32 for example) they will get picked up instead of the JRE/JDK you just installed, even if you added that one to the system path as well.

That's why you're still seeing a correct response from java -version but not from javac -version, as javac.exe isn't copied there.

Remove the java*.exe from your windows installation, install a 32 bit JDK, set your JAVA_HOME correctly, and add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your system path.

And oh, best not install a JDK to a place with spaces in the path, some versions don't like that.

Answer (score -1):

Find out you set your environment variable correctly. 
set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.8.0_121

and entry to path -> %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: You might want to upgrade. u121 is like 60 updates behind the latest